# How to add dynamic textbox in C# Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to add "other" option in my combobox lists, and when we selected it then dynamically a text box should appear and asks for other value like other talent things.

Thanks in advance,
Vengadesh

Answer (score 4):

You may need code like following :)

```
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.comboBox.Text.Equals("Other"))
        this.yourTextBox.Visible = true;
    else 
        this.yourTextBox.Visible = false;
}
```

Try it,

Comment: also mention to keep the `yourTextBox.Visible = false;` in form load as default.

Comment: `yourTextBox.Visible = comboBox.Text.Equals("Other");` is more succinct.

Answer (score 3):

there is no way to add TextBox in a ComboBox.
instead of that we can add items in the combobox.

here the combobox is the object of ComboBox class

```
combobox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem()
                   {
                    Text="Other"
                   });
```